# InstallShield Dynamic Dialogs

Tags: dynamic, dialog, installshield

I want to create an InstallShield Project that has a custom dialog containing a few text boxes that will be dynamically filled in with data from a text file (date, version info etc..) when the install runs. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that depends on where the file lives.

If the file exists already in the system (XML or INI formats, it could also be the registry), you could use System Search to find them. If found, the values would be stored in properties, which then you can use in your dialog (there's a Property field that you can use).

If it's a file you are installing then that's a different story, because at the time of the GUI execution, you will not have access to it.

If you provide more information then I could give some more specific advice. Things like: Where does the file live? who modifies it? is it part of the installation?

Regards,

Juan Carlos

Comment: It would be included with the "Support Files" so It would be on the root of the disc.

Comment: Why do you want it to be a text file? is it something that is modified dynamically? If not you could just create properties for the values you need and then just assign those properties to your dialog, with that you would get the fields pre-populated by default.

Comment: It is something that is modified dynamically. With each install the values will be different, but I don't want to re-build the whole install everytime.

Comment: In that case you could use the support files, which wouldn't be on the root of the disc, but on a temporary location that may not always be the same, so you need to use the SUPPORTDIR property in order to get access to that path. You can create a custom action that reads this text file and then puts the value into public properties that you can then use in the dialogs.

Comment: thanks, the public properties is the part I'm missing, I had it in the support files and knew about SUPPORTDIR but didn't know the next step.
Ill try that